# lessc - Firefox and Chrome live editor adds extra new lines

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, less

I am trying LESS live edit in Firefox and Chrome. For some reason, something in toolchain adds extra new lines, so that when `.less` source is viewed in the browser live editor all new lines are doubled.

This can be observed with both Firefox and Crhome.

My `lessc` command:

```
node_modules/less/bin/lessc less/libertymusicstore.less css/libertymusicstore.css --source-map
```

I am running on OSX. What could cause the extra new lines and how to get rid of them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently source `.less` files had been in some point been edited on Windows. This had caused Windows new lines to appear in the file, though the text editor (Sublime Text) picked the line endings as UNIX ones.

Converting the file newlines to Windows and then back to UNIX cured the issue and now both Chrome/Firefox identify newlines as UNIX newlines correctly.